# unified document editor

Tags: charts, presentation, vector-graphics, word-processor, spreadsheet

There are a lot of "Office" clones, but I'm looking for something that is a bit different.  I am looking for a document editor that has a single unified interface and which does not distinguish between word processing, spreadsheet, diagramming, outlining, and so forth but instead treats each of these as objects.  In addition,it needs to be "API first" or in other words, based on some kind of programming language so that it is extendible to add new object types.

A web browser seems like the most likely platform for this, as it has a document object model which allows any kind of document, but it seems like current document editors on the web like Google Docs are just reinvented Office all over again and are not innovating.  Each different type of document object is still silo-ed in its own application and can't natively co-exist with other types in the same page.

I am looking with has something like the old Microsoft "OLE" standard, which to some extent many office clones (like OpenOffice) seem to have some support for.  However, OLE itself isn't exactly what I'm looking for, as it merely hides the fact that you have different applications opening behind the scenes to provide editing of an embedded object of that type.  This seems much too heavy-weight and is upside down of the way it should be.  What I mean by this is, for example, you still have silo-ed opaque objects which rely on an external application to manipulate, as opposed to something like javascript/HTML where everything is based on a common environment.

Many years ago (>30?) this seemed to be the style of a few integrated environments (or maybe I'm mis-remembering them!), but is there anything like this today?  Specifically, a single application that supports all of the following natively, in the same document, without requiring separate apps like Microsoft Office, Open Office, etc. require?

- plain text (a la text editing)
- styled text (a la word processing)
- spreadsheet
- chart
- outline
- mind map
- presentation
- vector graphics
- raster graphics
- mathematical equations
- database (field objects, with db backend)
- audio
- video
- based on an underlying programmable model (a la javascript/HTML)

  1. so as to not be restricted from having new object types in the future
  2. so as to be able to be able to use the reactive spreadsheet model anywhere in the document

A web app would be fine, but it does not have to be.  No constraints as to operating system, free versus commercial, etc.

(not sure how to tag this, neither "document" nor "editor" are allowed tags)